# Vlookup Exact Match Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

hoping for some help understanding why `VLOOKUP` is not returning exact text matches and is instead showing partial matches. Below is an example of my data.

As you can see in the screenshots, item `R2FLG` returns a value of `136,861` which is correct, but item `R2FLGCLR` returns that same value when it shouldn't return anything because the exact item `R2FLGCLR` isn't in the `VLOOKUP` source data.

It seems to match the first part R2FLG and thus give it a value of `136,861`. I don't want that. I want it to `VLOOKUP` only exact text match.

Here is the `VLOOKUP` formula I'm using.

```
={"Total Parts Received";IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(C2:C,'Product/Service Import List'!AB:AC,2)))}
```

[image: Screenshot of the error]

[image: Screenshot of the source data]

Answer (score 4):

The reason your vlookup is getting a relative match is because "If is_sorted is TRUE or omitted, the **nearest match** (less than or equal to the search key) is returned. If all values in the search column are greater than the search key, #N/A is returned." See documentation for more details: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en

You can adjust your formula by adding in the false to the is-sorted criteria

```
={"Total Parts Received";IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(C2:C,'Product/Service Import List'!AB:AC,2,false)))}
```

Good luck!